# How can I add my sharding tables(sub-table) to flask-admin view?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have a big table "student", I want to split this table to sub-tables like:

`student_101, student_102 ... student_200`

I defined a dynamic model in model.py:

```
class StudentDynamic(DynamicBase):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True, comment=u"student name")
    phone = db.Column(db.BigInteger(), nullable=False, unique=True)
    class = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True, comment=u"class")
    ....

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role %r>' % self.__tablename__


def get_student_dynamic_table(suffix):
    tablename = 'student_%s' % suffix  # dynamic table name
    class_name = 'Student_%s' % suffix  # dynamic class name
    Model = type(class_name, (StudentDynamic,), {
        '__tablename__': tablename
    })
    return Model
```

Now, I want to add a view to flask-admin like other add-view, but I don't know how to add sub-tables in one view.

How can I merge these sub-tables to one view in flask-admin like one big table before?